# Eclipse , ADT , SDK , JDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I tried to use the new android L theme , therefore I updated the sdk, and then I came with an error that my ADT isn't matching to the SDK , tried to update but I got an error, so now im without Eclipse, without ADT , without SDK and without JDK, trying to install the ADT 23 bundle and its seems not to work.. Can someone guide me how to install the Eclipse? I don't know what to install first, what after, and I don't know how to download the files also.. I got Windows 7, 64 BIT..

I read about it a little bit trying to fix it.. someone said to me the problem is in the new sdk update, so I downloaded the old one :

android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows...

how can I install it with Eclipse and Jdk? ty

Comment: Install java,download eclipse ,install ADT from Help,Download SDK, but what is your mean about " its seems not to work " ?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Instead of the ADT, it opens me Eclipse juno.. something like this, I read about it and its a problem on the new SDK version.. and if I will install the new ADT from Help, it will say me to update the SDK, isn't it?

Comment: yes, you need update SDK version and ADT together

Comment: @shayanpourvatan that's the problem.. there is a problem in google new SDK/ADT .. its not working

Comment: have you problem with layout design ?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Nevermind, installed the old ADT and SDK, ty anyway.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I prefer to stay on the old ADT, working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aor android L or android 5.0, you need JDK 7 or higher

Steps for updating Eclipse:

1. Download Eclipse from the official site
2. Download and install JDK latest version
3. After installing the eclipse, go to Help > Install New Software.
4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
5. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the
       Name and the following URL for the Location:
       https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
6. Click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
   9.Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
9. If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
10. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.